# Are there any inhabited condominiums (joint sovereignties) apart from Brčko District?

Tags: international-travel, regulations, factoids, where-on-earth

The Wikipedia article on [condominium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium_%28international_law%29) (in the meaning of joint sovereignty) [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium_%28international_law%29#Current_condominia) a number of present condominiums, including [Brčko District](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C4%8Dko_District), which has almost 90000 inhabitants and is a condominimum between the [Republika Srpska](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republika_Srpska) and the [Federation of Bosnia and Herzegovina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina). It's probably not a major tourist destination, at least the railway station of Brčko town is rather small:

[image: Brčko railway station]

Wikipedia [reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C4%8Dko_%28city%29) that the station is served by one train per day.

The Wikipedia article on condominium also lists Hadf as a condominium between Oman and the Emirati state of Ajman, but the Wikipedia article on [Hadf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadf) lists it as simply lying in Oman. All other condominia listed by Wikipedia are either water or islets that are tiny, remote, or both. However, the list on Wikipedia may be incomplete.

> Are there any inhabited condominiums (in the meaning of a joint sovereignty) besides Brčko?

To qualify for my question, a condominium need not be shared by separate nations, but sub-national entities, such is the case for Brčko, also qualify.

Comment: in North America, a condominium is one unit of a shared set of units (eg one apartment in a building, one townhouse in a row of houses) where the owner does not own the land but shares ownership with the neighbours, while owning and being able to sell the unit. It might help your question if you defined this other use of condominium in your first paragraph. Toronto, for example, has hundreds of thousands of inhabited condominiums, as the word is used in Toronto.

Comment: Agree on that, by the definition of condominiums that is used here, I could also name hundreds of examples.

Comment: I see, I was not aware. I have adapted the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this is actually off-topic, I'm not sure now.

Comment: Is Brčko truly a condominium? Federation of BH and Republika Srpska are not sovereign nations, but federal units of Bosnia. *In theory*, Brčko is part of both, but in practice it has it's own assembly and local government, so it's more akin to Washington DC or Ciudad Mexico: an independent city exempt from jurisdiction of federal units.

Comment: I recently traveled around Bosnia, and one would often pass between RS and FBH. They aren't really different countries per se.

Comment: As indicated in the question, I understand that Brčko is shared between the two sub-national entities that both have considerable autonomy.

Comment: @gerrit: but same could be said about Brussels in relation with Flanders and Wallonia

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Baarle-Hertog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Hertog) / [Baarle-Nassau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau) is not formally condominium, but it's practically one city with interleaved Belgian and Dutch sovereignties.